# Prolog loop while dividing list over N lists

Tags: loops, prolog

What I want to achieve when doing `divide([1,2], 3, X).` is something like:
I Should just get all the permutations of the first list, divided over N lists.

```
X = [[],[],[1,2]] ;
X = [[],[],[2,1]] ;
X = [[],[2],[1]] ;
X = [[],[1],[2]] ;
X = [[],[1,2],[]] ;
X = [[],[2,1],[]] ;
X = [[],[],[2,1]] ;
X = [[],[],[1,2]] ;
X = [[],[1],[2]] ;
X = [[],[2],[1]] ;
X = [[],[2,1],[]] ;
X = [[],[1,2],[]] ;
X = [[2],[],[1]] ;
X = [[2],[1],[]] ;
X = [[1],[],[2]] ;
X = [[1],[2],[]] ;
X = [[1,2],[],[]] ;
X = [[2,1],[],[]] ;
```

but for some reason, if my list is longer than 2 items, the code below goes into a loop and shows way too much information.

```
% Divides a list over N sets
divide(_,N,[]) :- N < 1.
divide(Items,1,[Items]).
divide(Items,N,[Selected|Other]) :- N > 1, 
                                    sublistPerm(Items,Selected,Rest),
                                    N1 is N-1,
                                    divide(Rest,N1,Other).
```

the sublistPerm works as it should (you can test it if you want).

```
% Gets all power sets of a list and permutes them
sublistPerm(Items, Sel, Rest) :- sublist(Items, Temp1, Temp2),
                                 permutation(Temp1, Sel),
                                 permutation(Temp2, Rest).

% Gets all power sets of a list
sublist([], [], []).
sublist([X|XS], YS, [X|ZS]) :- sublist(XS, YS, ZS).
sublist([X|XS], [X|YS], ZS) :- sublist(XS, YS, ZS).
```

If you would do the effort of running the following code, you will see the redundant info that I am getting. I have ABSOLUTELY no idea why it doesn't just terminate, as it should. `divide([1,2,3], 3, X).`

As you can see in my example, there are no duplicates. Normally these won't occur, and if they occur, duplicates should be removed.

Thanks for anyone pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: How should it deal with duplicates?

Comment: @ScottHunter I edited it, thanks for the heads up. I Should just get all the permutations of the first list, divided over N lists.

Comment: If you are using SWI Prolog, a simple, total solution would be: `divide(L, N, D) :- permutation(L, P), length(D, N), append(D, P).` In your solution, I believe you're getting duplicate results coming from combinations of possible results from `sublistPerm` and `divide` queries in your recursive `divide` clause. So in one case, you might have a `Rest` of `[1,2,3]` and another case it might be `[2,3,1]` but the recursive call will exhaust all the permutations of each of these all over again.

Comment: This question is unrelated to loops. Your goal is terminating!

Comment: I believe @false told you everything to fix your existing code (there are just two places). Is there anything not acceptable in the answer?

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code, looping is none of them. We can set that issue apart very quickly:

```
?- divide([1,2], 3, X), false.
```

This terminates. No termination issues with this query.

There are some redundant solutions. But again this is not really an issue. However, what is most problematic is that your relation is incomplete. The minimal example is:

```
 ?- divide([1,2], 1, [[2,1]]).
```

which should succeed but fails. So let's attack this issue first. The fact

```
 divide(Items,1,[Items]).
```

has to be generalized to cover all permutations.

```
 divide(Items,1,[ItemsP]) :-
    permutation(Items, ItemsP).
```

For the redundant answers/solutions the second goal `permutation/2` is not needed, you can replace it by `(=)/2` or rewrite your program accordingly.